# SQLAlchemy adding column with aggregate function to a dynamic loader list (AppenderQuery)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I get an incorrect record set, while adding an aggregate function like `func.sum` on a dynamic relationship. I have listed out a sample code below to demonstrate this.

```python
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    relationship,
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    backref
    )
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Table,
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    func
)
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
import transaction

Base = declarative_base()
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = Column(String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    article_list = relationship("Article", backref="user", lazy="dynamic")

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(25), nullable=False)
    duration = Column(Integer)

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary="tag_map",
                        backref=backref("article_list", lazy="dynamic"))


tag_map_table = Table(
    'tag_map', Base.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), nullable=False),
    Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('articles.id'), nullable=False))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tag_test.sqlite')
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with transaction.manager:
    t1 = Tag(name='software')
    t2 = Tag(name='hardware')
    john = User(userid='john')

    a1 = Article(title='First article', duration=300)
    a1.user = john
    a1.tags.append(t1)
    a1.tags.append(t2)
    DBSession.add(a1)

    a2 = Article(title='Second article', duration=50)
    a2.user = john
    a2.tags.append(t1)
    a2.tags.append(t2)
    DBSession.add(a1)
```

As we see above in the code, I have added two tags for both the articles. Now I want to query the articles written by the user 'John' grouped by tags along with it I want to find the sum of each tag duration.

```python
john = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.userid=='john').first()

res =  john.article_list.join(Article.tags).add_column(
    func.sum(Article.duration)).group_by(Tag.id)
for article, tsum in res:
    print ("Article : %s, Sum duration : %d" % (article.title, tsum))
```

The query generated for `res` is

```sql
SELECT articles.id AS articles_id, articles.title AS articles_title, articles.duration AS articles_duration, articles.user_id AS articles_user_id, sum(articles.duration) AS sum_1 
FROM articles JOIN tag_map AS tag_map_1 ON articles.id = tag_map_1.article_id JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_map_1.tag_id 
WHERE :param_1 = articles.user_id GROUP BY tags.id
```

which when executed directly on the sqlite database yields two rows corresponding to the two tags

```
2|Second article|50|1|350
2|Second article|50|1|350
```

Whereas, the results returned by SQLAlchemy reflect only one row

> Article : Second article, Sum duration : 350

But, if I add an extra column to contain tag-name in the `AppenderQuery` object

```python
res = john.article_list.join(Article.tags).add_column(Tag.name).add_column(
    func.sum(Article.duration)).group_by(Tag.id)

for article, tag_name, tsum in res:
    print ("Article : %s, Tag : %s, Sum duration : %d" % (
        article.title, tag_name, tsum))
```

I get proper results

```
Article : Second article, Tag : software, Sum duration : 350
Article : Second article, Tag : hardware, Sum duration : 350
```

So, what is the right way of using aggregate functions on `AppenderQuery` object in order to get categorized results?